# Event-Driven PHP Framework?

Tags: php, design-patterns, frameworks, dependency-injection

I'm wondering if there are any completely event-drive frameworks out there for PHP which are based around dependency injection for decoupling. I know there are some frameworks that make *use* of these patterns - but in the end the entire life-cycle of the application is still pre-defined and linear in style.

For example, most frameworks are built to receive, process, and return results from HTTP requests. An event drive framework would have handlers for that, but also be able to be used for new purposes like background processing, command line interaction, or other non-standard use cases.

Comment: What do you mean with event driven? Like NodeJS, Twisted or EventMachine? Since PHP executes per request it will always be kind of linear. And I wouldn't want to have programs with not pre-defined behaviour.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds to me like the [Photon framework](http://www.photon-project.com/) fits closest to your description - the key point is that you can't have event-driven code  without php running in a daemon-like process. Your choice of webserver in fact dictates whether what you ask is possible or not - photon is dependent on [mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org/).

Answer (score 9):

I have never used it for a project personally, but I believe that [Prado](http://www.pradosoft.com/) covers what you are asking. It is componentised, but I cannot be sure about the dependency injection aspect.

From their site:

> PRADOTM is a component-based and event-driven programming framework for developing Web applications in PHP 5. PRADO stands for
>   PHP Rapid Application Development Object-oriented.

I know of it because one of my university class mates designed the logo and website for the project.

Comment: Prado website is not working but this works https://github.com/pradosoft/prado

Answer (score 6):

Not used it, but I believe in addition to Prado, which Treffynnon has mentioned, [Qcodo](http://www.qcodo.com/) is a pure event-driven framework.

Comment: Good memory! I had it in my mind it was _Qdoco_ rather than _Qcodo_ and couldn't find it when mentioning Prado below!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking what is around as well and i came across [p4e](http://p4a.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Welcome_to_P4A_-_PHP_For_Applications) which is based on zend framework,and [nette](http://nette.org/en/), hope it can help!

Answer (score 0):

Off the bat there are these 2 as well:
[Zend Framework 2](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2) (still in beta)
[symfony 2](http://www.symfony-project.org/)

Both have all the things you are looking for I believe.

Comment: Are you sure that zf2 is event driven?

Comment: Not in the classical low-level sense like nginx or anything using an event-loop to underpin language execution. However in userland, ZF2 modules/classes etc are designed to able to work in an event driven fashion with each other, which is what I think the OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony2. Simple as that.
http://symfony.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yii ,It is a component based and event-driven framework, Pure OOP and MVC. It is very clean and neat. Check it out.

http://www.yiiframework.com

Answer (score 0):

The [Qbix Platform](http://platform.qbix.com) is heavily event-driven in PHP, although it does not use dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Reactphp is what you are looking for.